# Using file upload control how to upload empty folder in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using file upload controls in asp.net c# how to upload empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload folders anywhere. Your site needs to give the user the opportunity to create folders, eg with a TextField for the name of the folder and a button to submit the request. But you are not able to upload an empty folder. Not even a folder containing files. In this case only the files will be uploaded. Maybe you wanna use a ZIP file to upload an "archived folder".

Comment: If a folder contain files then we can get relativepath like : Directory/filename. Is it possible to get empty folder relativepath.

Comment: If the zip format supports it, and your server code can understand that zip format then yes. Most zips allow you to do include the folder structure, but it depends how the user saves it. You'd need to make sure the user was aware how to create the zip file correctly